# Нельзя добавить элемент через "Эрмитаж"

Tags: настройка, битрикс

Есть страница на сайте с новостями. Отображается несколько новостей. Но их нельзя править через "Эрмитаж". Можно добавить новый элемент, существующие нельзя править. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?
    $this->AddEditAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['EDIT_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_EDIT"));
    $this->AddDeleteAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['DELETE_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_DELETE"), array("CONFIRM" => GetMessage('CT_BNL_ELEMENT_DELETE_CONFIRM')));
?>
    <div class="news" id="<?=$this->GetEditAreaId($arItem['ID']);?>">
```

добавь в шаблон компонента вот это